# What's the best method to create Audio Podcast Gallery on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, gallery, podcast

I'm currently learning wordpress and I have a project where I need to create an audio podcast gallery, so users can find all podcasts, read description and download it.

What is the best method to achieve this gallery? Do I create a podcast page on wordpress and use custom fields meta function? or maybe there's a plugin? I just need to know the right method to achieve this.

I need more info about best method to create this gallery. The idea is very similar to this: http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts

Answer (score 0):

I created a podcasts category. Then view the category's page, eg example.com/?cat=4 to see all of your podcasts.

Note, your url will have a different cat number.